# ASP.NET Where do I store required DLL's

Tags: c#, dll

I have a solution that references a few class libraries. The site requires these dlls for it to work. Where would be the best place to store these required dlls so when people check out my project they are ready to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my setup:

```
-SorurceControlRoot
   /SRC
       MySolution.sln       
       /MyFirstProject
          /bin(SC ignore)
          /obj(SC ignore)
          MyClass.cs
          MyFirstproject.csproj (includes info what .dlls the project needs)
   /LIBS
       MyReferencedLib1.dll
       MyReferencedLib2.dll
   /DOCS
       TechnicalSpec.doc
```

Never had any problem with it. Do you want to see the dlls in VS or want them in the solution for TFS so just add solutionfolder linked to the LIBS folder.

Answer (score 1):

Anywhere that's logical when someone wants to look for it.

I keep it in a directory called "Libs" at the root of the solution.

Answer (score -2):

Store them in the bin folder of your application

Comment: No thanks, checking in the bin and obj folders makes only a big mess.